# How to access a service in an ember acceptance test

Tags: ember.js

Running ember 1.13.6 and ember-cli

I have an ember component which I am trying to acceptance test. It's state is very closely tied to the state of a service within my app and so I would like to directly access that service and change its properties from within my acceptance test.

I have been trying things along the lines of
`this.application.__container__.lookup['service:side-bar'])`
and
`this.application.__container__.cache['service:side-bar'])`

but I cannot seem to get the actual active service singleton which my app is using and which I could call `get()` and `set()` on.

if I try to use Ember.inject.service i get an obscure error `Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object(…)` which sort of sounds like a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm successfully getting at a service in 1.13.x by doing something like this:

```
let myService;
module("Acceptance | xxxxx", {
  beforeEach() {
    this.application = startApp()
    myService = this.application.__container__.lookup('service:my-service');
  }
});
```

Your problem might be that you're trying to use array notation (`lookup['my-service']`) rather than method invocation (`lookup('my-service')`).

Hope this helps!